# How to used multiclassification and regression together?

Tags: python, catboost

There is a mixed data set for multiclassification and regression problems. The result of the classification should be based on the result of the regression. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, my friend. Based on the details of your question, you need to first un-mix the dataset, then do the regression, and finally perform classification using the result of the regression.

Cheers.